# How to preserve tags in strings containing html

Tags: php, string, tags, converters

I have the following code:

```
<?php
     $result = '<test>hello</test>';
     echo $result;
```

When I execute it, then I only receive

```
hello
```

It seems so, that PHP deletes these tags in the string, when i try to give it out. How can I preserve these tags in the string?

Comment: Take `view source` from your browser and you will see the tags.

Comment: They aren't deleted, but you're `echo`ing them to a browser, which in turn parses and renders the tags..

Comment: yes, you probably need to change your question to "how to display tags in strings"... they are preserved !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can use [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) php function : in your case,

```
echo htmlentities($result);
```

or

```
echo htmlentities("<test>hello</test>");
```

better approach will be

```
htmlspecialchars()
```

Comment: Less `htmlentities()` and moar `htmlspecialchars()` please.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that php 'deletes' them. Most probably you are viewing the output in a browser which just doesn't display them. Rightclick on the window and use "Show sourcecode" to see it all.

Answer (score 2):

Well it is intepreted as a part of the website it tries to render. to see the tag you need to encode them.

Your example would be:

```
<?php

$result = '&lt;test&gt;hello&lt;/test&gt;';
echo $result;

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just the browser that renders HTML, and thus "hides" the tags.

If you want to see the markup as well, wrap your string into a `<pre>` tag:

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';

echo '<p>Hello, World!</p>';

echo '</pre>';
```